# How to check apache version

Tags: centos

CentOS 6.9
There are 2 versions of apache are existing on my CentOS. One installed by "make install httpd", another installed by "yum install httpd". How do I check what version are running

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You first need to find out where are those binaries stored. For this you may use the [whereis](https://linux.die.net/man/1/whereis) command.

```
whereis httpd
```

The output will give you the different path for the files httpd like this:

```
httpd: /usr/sbin/httpd /usr/lib64/httpd /etc/httpd /usr/share/httpd /usr/share/man/man8/httpd.8.gz
```

Then, for the binaries, you can check the version using the path with the attribute `-v`

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -v
```

Output:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Oct 19 2017 20:39:16
```

---

For the yum installed version, you may also use the following command:

```
sudo yum list installed httpd
Installed Packages
httpd.x86_64                          2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6
```

---

Another last solution is to use: `rpm -q httpd`

Comment: Thank you, but I was wondering that what version is activating. For example, when I run `service httpd stop` 
and then `/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start`
so the httpd version on /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl folder is activating.

Answer (score 5):

You can check **Apache Version in Ubuntu** by using this Command -

```
apachectl -v
```

The Result will be like this -

```
vishal@vishal:~$ apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2020-08-12T19:46:17
```